# Athena unnest for nested Array string column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a column in athena whose datatype is string and data looks like:

```
[{'main_key1': {'key1': value, 'key2': value2}, 'outer_key': outer_value},{'main_key2': {'key1': value, 'key2': value2}, 'outer_key': outer_value1}]
```

I have to split the value of this list (outer_key1) across multiple rows.

for eg:

| id | outer_key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | outer_value |
| 1 | outer_value1 |

Can anyone please help if there is a way to acheive this

I already tried json_parse, unnest but everything is ending in some kind of exception

Comment: Is it `'key1': value` or `'key1': 'value'`

Comment: its 'key1': value , value is int

Comment: If it is int then it can be valid JSON - check the first option in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your data actually is. If actually is a valid JSON string then you can process it as JSON:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(some_json) as(
    values ('[{"main_key1": {"key1": 1, "key2": "value2"}, "outer_key": "outer_value"},{"main_key2": {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}, "outer_key": "outer_value1"}]')
)

-- query
select json_extract(js, '$.outer_key')
from dataset,
     unnest(cast(json_parse(some_json) as array(json))) as t(js);
```

Output:

```
     _col0
----------------
 "outer_value"
 "outer_value1"
```

If it is just a string then you will need to use regular expressions. Something to get you started (the regular expression can change based on actual data):

```sql
with dataset(some_str) as(
    values ('[{''main_key1'': {''key1'': value, ''key2'': value2}, ''outer_key'': outer_value},{''main_key2'': {''key1'': value, ''key2'': value2}, ''outer_key'': outer_value1}]')
)

select val
from dataset,
     unnest(regexp_extract_all(some_str, '''outer_key''\s?:\s?\b(\w*)\b', 1)) as t(val);
```

Output:

```
     val
--------------
 outer_value
 outer_value1
```